# How to optimize if there are many sub classes with similar name

Tags: c++, optimization

here is what i write:

```
...
#define JOIN(x,y) x##y
class A
{
public:
    A(){}; 
    virtual ~A(){};
}

class AA : public A
{
public:
    AA(){};
    virtual ~AA(){};
}

class AB : public A
{
public:
    AB(){};
    virtual ~AB(){};
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        A *a = NULL;
        if(i == 0)
            a = new JOIN(A,A);
        else
            a = new JOIN(A,B);
        delete a;
        a = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what if there are class AC,AD,...,AZ, there are many if...else... and JOINs

how to decrease counts of if...else... and look more comfortable!

Comment: Feels like an XY problem.  Why so many classes with similar names?

Comment: In which aspect is AA different from AB? Could templates help?

Comment: `switch`, and dear lord don't abuse macros

Comment: To me it looks like *more* work to write `JOIN(A,B)` than writing `AB`.

Comment: nitpicking: when asking how to optimize code, you should pay special attention to the correctness of the code you show, because optimizing wrong code is kinda pointless. (I am talking about missing `;`, but I hope you get my point ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to factorize your code, you might use template:

```
template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    A* a = new T;
    // ...
    delete a;
}
```

or even

```
template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    T a;
    // ...
}
```

and then

```
int main()
{
    foo<AA>();
    foo<AB>();
    foo<AC>();
    foo<AD>();
    foo<AE>();
}
```